# How do you print a ruby hash using the new ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby-1.9.3

I want to print my ruby hashes using the new syntax (i.e. {hello: 1, world: 2} vs. {:hello => 1, :world => 2}.

I've tried pretty print `pp`:

`irb(main):001:0> {hello: 1, hi: 2}
=> {:hello=>1, :hi=>2}`

but to no avail. Is there a way to do this?